# Server doesn't start

Tags: node.js

Today I try open my server, but it doesn't start

Full code - https://github.com/meln1337/error-proxy

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const config = require('config')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json({extended: true}))

app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth.routes'))

const PORT = config.get('port') || 5000

async function start () {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://borys:1q2w3e4r5t6y7u8i@cluster0-puuhz.mongodb.net/app', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true
        })
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`App has been started on port ${PORT}...`)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Server error', e.message)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

start()
```

config/default.json

```
{
    "port": 5000
}
```

Does the server not start due to mongodb?
If not then why does the server not start?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful to include the error message you are seeing when you try to start the server. It's a lot of work to pull down your code and try to run it, so including as much information as possible in your post will help you reach the widest amount of peole and get you a better answer.

Comment: When something like this happens, YOU need to do some of your own debugging and only post here after you've done that.  We can't debug it for you.  The type of debugging you would do would report anything that shows in the console, add more `console.log()` statements to find out exactly where the code goes or fails.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run it, locally, with a few changes to "remove" missing files (i.e., changing your mongodb uri to a localhost thingy).

Have you checked your console? When I run it, I get (assuming I have `config`), `TypeError: config.get is not a function`. So unless I'm missing something, that's your first issue.

The second is that, for me, obviously the Mongodb instance won't work. I *assume* that's not true for you - you don't get `error querySrv ENODATA` - but that's worth checking too.

Finally, if your question is still about mongodb, why not remove that? Just comment out the `await...` bit, and see if the server starts?